# Problem with understanding the easy proof of Ptolemy's theorem converse

Tags: geometry, proof-verification

I have been struggling to prove the converse of Ptolemy's theorem. I have managed to prove it by using the sines theorem, but it seems that I have found an easier solution:

The theorem itself:

If in the quadrilateral ABCD $AB \cdot CD + BC \cdot AD = AC \cdot BD$ then it is cyclic.

**Proof of the converse of Ptolemy's Theorem.** 
Let's choose such point $D^*$ so that $$\angle \, CAD^* = \angle \, BAD = \alpha+\tilde{\alpha} \,\,\, \text{ and } \,\,\, \angle \, ACD^* = \angle \, ABD = \beta$$

Assume that $$AB \cdot CD + BC \cdot AD = AC \cdot BD$$ Then  $$CD + DD^*  = \frac{AB \cdot CD + BC \cdot AD}{AB} = \frac{AC \cdot BD}{AB} = CD^*$$ which is possible if and only if the point $D$ lies on the line $CD^*$. Therefore, $$\angle \, ACD = \angle \, ACD^* = \angle ABD = \beta$$ which means that the quadrilateral $ABCD$ is cyclic.

(By Futurologist)

Here I don't understand why if the angles ACD and ADB are equal, then the quadrilateral is cyclic. Could you please help me figure that out?

Answer (score 0):

we have in any circle angles in the same segment are equal, this statement actually answered the question.

but if want to know different proofs for this well-known theorem here is the list

we can find the different proofs of Ptolemy's theorem in the following papers

http://article.sciencepublishinggroup.com/html/10.11648.j.mcs.20160104.14.html

http://jcgeometry.org/Articles/Volume4/Krishna.pdf

http://www.msme.us/2017-1-3.pdf